# onClick Method not working Android

Tags: android

I have a LandingPage with two Buttons, each pointing to a different activity.. None of the onClick Methods is functioning.. I know this is supposed to be really basic stuff but I cannot find the solution..

My code is the following:

```
public class LandingPage extends AppCompatActivity {

Button log_in, sign_up;
Typeface tfc_button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_landing_page);

    log_in = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LogIn_Button);
    sign_up = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SignUp_Button);

    setFontType();
    addSoundtoButtons();

}

public void addSoundtoButtons(){
    //Add Sound to the Buttons
    final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.button_click_sound);
    log_in.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });
    sign_up.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });
}

public void setFontType(){

    //Set Font Type for Buttons
    tfc_button = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/TEMPSITC.TTF");

    log_in = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LogIn_Button);
    sign_up = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SignUp_Button);

    log_in.setTypeface(tfc_button);
    sign_up.setTypeface(tfc_button);

}

public void OnClickButtonLogin(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SignInPage.class);
    startActivity(intent);}

public void OnClickButtonSignUp(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SignUpPage.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

My Activity Layout is the Following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/landingpagenormal"
    tools:context="com.example.gebruiker.prototype1oneplayerpurevisualisation.Activities.LandingPage">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/LogIn_Button"
        android:layout_width="171dp"
        android:layout_height="57dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
        android:background="@drawable/login_button"
        android:onClick="OnClickButtonLogin"
        android:text="Log In"
        android:textColor="#FFEAEA"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/SignUp_Button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/SignUp_Button"
        android:layout_width="171dp"
        android:layout_height="57dp"
        android:onClick="OnClickButtonSignUp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="38dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
        android:background="@drawable/signup_button"
        android:text="Sign Up"
        android:textColor="#FFEAEA"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The Layout of the Landscape Mode of my Activity is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/landingpagelandscape"
    tools:context="com.example.gebruiker.prototype1oneplayerpurevisualisation.Activities.LandingPage">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/LogIn_Button"
        android:layout_width="171dp"
        android:layout_height="57dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/login_button"
        android:onClick="OnClickButtonLogin"
        android:text="Log In"
        android:textColor="#FFEAEA"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/SignUp_Button"
        android:layout_width="171dp"
        android:layout_height="57dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:onClick="OnClickButtonSignUp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/signup_button"
        android:text="Sign Up"
        android:textColor="#FFEAEA"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: From the code you've posted, nothing is wrong (and when I copy it to my IDE, everything works). Have you omitted something that could affect the button clicks? For instance, if (for some reason) you called `log_in.setOnClickListener(null)` then that would explain why it's not working.

Comment: I have added the omitted code and adapted as suggested.. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so, you have two conflicting things. First, the `onClick` attribute in your layout:

> ```
> android:onClick="OnClickButtonLogin"
> ```

Second, the `setOnClickListener()` in your Activity:

> ```
> log_in.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>     @Override
>     public void onClick(View view) {
>         mediaPlayer.start();
>     }
> });
> ```

The second one will override the first. You should still see/hear the effects of `mediaPlayer.start()`, but you won't ever get a call to `OnClickButtonLogin()`. If you wanted to have both, you could remove the `setOnClickListener()` call and just add `mediaPlayer.start()` to the `OnClickButtonLogin()` method:

```
public void OnClickButtonLogin(View view) {
    mediaPlayer.start();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```